# How to match repeated patterns?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match:

```
some.name.separated.by.dots
```

But I don't have any idea how.

I can match a single  part like this

```
 \w+\.
```

How can I say "repeat that"

Comment: Is this for ASCII or Unicode character data — **and are you *sure*?** What programming language is it? There is no reasonable way to create a regex without knowing the target language, as the same syntax can mean something altogether different in different implementations.

Comment: @tchrist This is for Java ( as properly inferred by Bart ) I have run some test with the provided accepted answer and is working fine ( so far  ) :)

Comment: The answer is ASCII-only.  Hope that suffices.

Comment: how about `\w{1,}`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)+
```

The `+` after `(?: ... )` tell it to match what is inside the parenthesis one or more times.

Note that `\w` only matches ASCII characters, so a word like `café` wouldn't be matches by `\w+`, let alone words/text containing Unicode.

### EDIT

The difference between `[...]` and `(?:...)` is that `[...]` always matches a single character. It is called a "character set" or "character class". So, `[abc]` does **not** match the string `"abc"`, but matches one of the characters `a`, `b` or `c`.

The fact that `\w+[\.\w+]*` also matches your string is because `[\.\w+]` matches a `.` or a character from `\w`, which is then repeated zero or more time by the `*` after it. But, `\w+[\.\w+]*` will therefor also match strings like `aaaaa` or `aaa...........`.

The `(?:...)` is, as I already mentioned, simply used to group characters (and possible repeat those groups).

More info on character sets: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

More info on groups: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

### EDIT II

Here's an example in Java (seeing you post mostly Java answers):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "some.text.here only but not Some other " + 
                "there some.name.separated.by.dots and.we are done!";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

which will produce:

```
some.text.here
some.name.separated.by.dots
and.we
```

Note that `m.group(0)` and `m.group()` are equivalent: meaning "the entire match".

Comment: Based on your answer I came up with this: `\w+[\.\w+]*` ( I think I'll need those parenthesis later ). Could you explain why `()` and `[]` do work?

Comment: @Oscar: Bart's answer handles this.

Comment: @SilentGost yeap, I just noticed :P ( copy/paste error )  I meant to say I use `[]` instead of `()` I can't really understand the difference though. I only know the former doesn't create a group

Comment: Thanks!! I thought I was creating a class with all that or something :) So, I guess I just should take into account the group created by the parenthesis, if I am to create another group with the whole thing,   right? For instance: `(\w+(\.\w+)*)`

Comment: @OscarRyz, there is no real need to group the entire pattern, since most languages will let you access what is matched through group 0 (in Java: `group(0)`, in PHP: `$match[0]`). So, that would leave just: `\w+(\.\w+)*`

Comment: Yeap, but I am to extract it from other bigger string like: `some.text.here Some other there` so I'm thinking in `(\w+(\.\w+)*)\s+.*` to get `some.text.here` only but not `Some other there`  Does it make sense? :-S

Comment: @OscarRyz, these silly small comment boxes, let me whip up an example.

Comment: Aha!!... got it. Thank you again.  It's a shame I can't double upvote.

Comment: @Bart: Certainly `\w+` will match Unicode just fine in some regex languages. A Java regex that means what `\w` is *supposed* to mean is `[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]]`.

Comment: @tchrist, `\w` or `[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]]`, what the difference? :) True, of course, certain implementations do have proper Unicode support.

Answer (score 3):

This will also work:

```
(\w+(\.|$))+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` to match 0 or 1 of the preceeding parts, `*` to match 0 to any amount of the preceeding parts, and `+` to match at least one of the preceeding parts.

So `(\w\.)?` will match w. and a blank, `(\w\.)*` will match r.2.5.3.1.s.r.g.s. and a blank, and `(\w\.)+` will match any of the above but not a blank.

If you want to match something like your example, you'll need to do `(\w+\.)+`, which means 'match at least one non whitespace, then a period, and match at least one of these'.

Comment: Who voted me down? I wouldn't mind learning more about regexes if I've gone wrong somewhere, since I'm pretty new to them. Is is since it will match `foo.foo.` but not `foo.foo`?

Comment: I didn't downvote you ( didn't upvote you either ) but judging by the others downvotes I would say yes, that's the reason. Actually none of your regexp do matched my string :(

Comment: You may need to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score -3):

```
(\w+\.)+
```

Apparently, the body has to be at least 30 characters. I hope this is enough.

Comment: This will require a trailing period, contrary to his example.