# Match characters prior to word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I’ve been at it for many hours now and finally decided to give up and ask.

I need a JavaScript Regex to match against things like this:

- asdfURL
- 123URL
- @#URL

Basically anything before the word URL except `<` and `>`.

I was able to handle characters after the word (below), but not prior. And I need both before and after!

```
/^(?=\bURL)[^<> ]+$/i
```

So essentially `$B#5t4rg3b4URLDFSGre4r` should match and `FGWEG$R$G$?>URL<9TGSG` should not.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739759/how-to-match-repeated-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use groups

```
var myRegexp =/([^<> ]*)URL([^<> ]*)/ig;
var match = myRegexp.exec(input);
alert(match[1]);//before
alert(match[2]);//after
```

Comment: This worked great. Unfortunately I forgot to add that I need to parse a block of text for matches and not just the one string. (But alas my stupidity doesn't make this any less correct.)