# Regex String Format

Tags: regex

I'm not really good at regex. I want to create a string validator with the following format :

> key=value;

I want to make sure the input has a `=` to separate key/value and a `;` at the end of the string.

Here is my regex :

> \w(=)\w(;)

it only match with one character, e.g: `a=b;`. Can anybody help me to make it able to match with input like this `a=bbb;` or `aa=bbbb;`

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `\w+(=)\w+(;)`. If it works, I will write a proper answer. And you do not need the parenthesis, actually - if I am not mistaken.

Comment: woooah... thank you. it works

Comment: `\w` will only match one character, to match more than one add a `+` quantifier i.e. `\w+`. Also you don't need `()` around the `=` and `;`. And you should probably anchor the regex too: `^\w+=\w+;$`

Comment: `\w+=.*;` for alphanumeric keys (plus underscore) and any value, even empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match repeated patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739759/how-to-match-repeated-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will work:

```
\w+=\w+;
```

`+` means that you want one ore more characters, and the parenthesis are not needed.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/sPQahW/1).

---

To be able to choose exactly which characters are allowed, you need to use lists.

For example, to match `ds2@=12!2%;` you need to use:

```
[\w@]+=[\w%!]+;
```

In the lists you add the characters you want matched. The two lists do not need to be the same.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/sPQahW/3).

Comment: Hey.. can you help to make it able to accept input like `ds2@=12!2%;`